# Project Organization in C Best Practices

Tags: c, project-organization

I am wondering what the best practices are for organizing a large C project are. It is a professional project, not an open source one, likely to be stored in a Git repository. How should things be sorted? Where should structures go? When should one use functions attached to structures versus functions that take a structure as a parameter?

In terms of laying out the files in the project, how should things come together? What naming conventions are most appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661307/recommendations-for-structuring-complex-applications-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do in your situation is just make sure your whole team is on the same page. This point can't be stressed enough. Have a standardized method of doing things and make sure your doing it.

Answer (score -2):

For large projects, my personal method is that everything gets its own folder. i.e.:

Root --> (Classes, Structs)

Classes --> (ClassA, ClassB)

Structs --> (StructA, StructB)

If needed, you can further split up a StructA or Struct B...

StructA --> (Methods,Struct)

etc.