# Best place to define a struct for a library

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Currently I am writing a library for a communication protocol. For this task I need this struct:

```
typedef struct _C8B10 {
    unsigned int six :6;
    unsigned int four :4;
} C8B10;
```

But where should I define it? I have one 'main' *.h-file that is included by all other libs. The *.c-files for each lib include only the 'parent' *.h-file. The structure is similar to a tree:

```
Main.h
      Main.c
  Child.h
      Child.c
  Child2.h
      Child2.c
  ....
```

The children always include the `Main.h` and the `child.c` their parents. But in one library I get the error, that the type is not defined.

At the moment it is declared in the Main.h-file. But where is the best place to put it into?

Comment: if you get the error, the header is not included (or included after you try to use it)

Comment: I thought so, too. But even if I clean the project, delete the inclusion and include the library again nothing changes and the error appears like before.

Comment: is this a typo: "the children always include ... child.c" ? as a suggestion: always use include guards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: No, it should mean that 'Child.h' etc. includes 'main.h' and 'child.c' includes 'child.h'. So there is a tree structure and no circles.

All *.h-files have a unique include guard.

Answer (score 2):

### Namespace conflict

Whatever else you do, you should change the structure tag from `_C8B10` to something that does not trample on the namespace reserved to the implementation.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011
>
> #### 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> ¶1 Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and
>   optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions
>   subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file
>   scope identifiers.
>   — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>   underscore are always reserved for any use.
>   — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
>   with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

Names starting with an underscore are risky; they are there for providers of the system libraries.  Obviously, if your library is part of the implementation, this doesn't apply to you, but I think it unlikely that you'd be asking the question if that were the case.

If it was my code, I'd simply drop the underscore: `typedef struct C8B10 { ... } C8B10;` is fine (`typedef` names are in the ordinary identifiers namespace, the structure tag is in the tags namespace, and the two do not conflict).

---

### Header file organization

Your diagram is backwards from the way most people normally write such diagrams.  The source code includes the headers, so it might be diagrammed as:

```
main.c
    main.h
child1.c
    child1.h
child2.c
    child2.h
```

However, that can't be the whole story.  You create a header to share declarations between source files; a header that is included by just one file is not strictly necessary (though there can be legitimate reasons for creating such files).  Either the file `main.c` uses some of the functions (and types — and maybe macros or even global variables, perish the thought) defined in `child1.c` or the code in `child1.c` uses the material from `main.c` (or possibly both).  Therefore, either `main.c` should include `child1.h` or `child1.c` should include `main.h` or both.

The other aspect that you need to consider with a library is 'how will clients of the library use the code?'  This is crucial.  What header will the client code need?  What functions will the client code need?  Will the client code need any type definitions?  Will the client code need to access the members of the C8B10 structure, or will they only need to treat it as an opaque type?

Your external header — the one used by clients of the library — should be as small as possible, but self-contained.  Let's assume that the external header is `c8b10.h`.  If the client source code has `#include "c8b10.h"` as the first or only header in the source file, the code in the header should compile.  If your interface uses `size_t`, for example, you need to `#include <stddef.h>` in `c8b10.h`.

In your circumstances, I'd expect that your `C8B10` structure should be defined in `main.h` and both `child1.c` and `child2.c` should include `main.h`.  It is likely that `main.c` should also include both `child1.h` and `child2.h`.  And `main.h` should include the external `c8b10.h` header, so in fact every file includes that.

```
main.c
    main.h
        c8b10.h
    child1.h
    child2.h
child1.c
    main.h
        c8b10.h
    child1.h
child2.c
    main.h
        c8b10.h
    child2.h
```

Whether `child2.c` needs to include `child1.h` and whether `child1.c` needs to include `child2.h` depends on how the code is written and which of the services provided by each file are used where.

You might find it more sensible to have just two headers — the external `c8b10.h` header and one internal header `c8b10-private.h`.  The `c8b10-private.h` header would be included by each source file in the library.  The first header it would include is the external `c8b10.h` header (to help automatically check that the `c8b10.h` header is self-contained).  The `c8b10-private.h` header would correspond to the merger of `main.h`, `child1.h` and `child2.h`, minus the externally accessible content defined in `c8b10.h`.  This leads to:

```
main.c
    c8b10-private.h
        c8b10.h
child1.c
    c8b10-private.h
        c8b10.h
child2.c
    c8b10-private.h
        c8b10.h
```

The key point to remember is that headers are for communicating between source files.  The rest follows largely automatically from that.

Comment: Thx for the amazing answer! I renamed the struct without '_'.

The user should implement 'main.h' and he there are around 5 methods that will do everything. The user dont need to work with the defined struct. It is just for calculation inside the given functions.

'main.h' is included in every other header file and the implementation files include only their header file and not 'main.h'.

So far everything works fine, but one header file throws the error even the implementation of this header uses this struct and compiles without any error or warning...

Comment: See also [Should I use `#include` in headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers/) for some more information on self-contained (and idempotent) headers. There's also useful information at [Design Principles, Best Practices and Design Patterns for C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492446/design-principles-best-practices-and-design-patterns-for-c-or-procedural-progr/).  If you have global variables, read the advice at [What are extern variables in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/)

Answer (score 1):

Header files are usually used like Java's interfaces in the sense that headers define what information is available outside of the implementation.

If the struct should be available outside of the implementation define it in a header, otherwise define it in once in a .c file which is included in the other .c files.