# Multiple Header Files and Function Prototypes in C

Tags: c, design-patterns

Assuming that I work on a big project in C with multiple `.c` files, is there any reason why I should prefer to have multiple header files instead of a single header file?

And another question:

Let's say that I have 3 files: `header.h`, `main.c` and `other.c`.
I have a function named `func()` that is defined and used only in the file `other.c`. Should I place the function prototype in the header file or in the file `other.c` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Multiple headers vs a single header.

   A primary reason for using multiple headers is that some of the code may be usable independently of the rest, and that code should probably have its own header.  In the extreme, each source file (or small group of source files) that provides a service should have its own header that defines the interface to the service.

   Also note that what goes in the header is the information needed to use the module — function declarations and type declarations needed by the function declarations (you don't have global variables, do you?).  The header should not include headers only needed by the implementation of the module.  It should not define types only needed by the implementation of the module.  It should not define functions that are not part of the formal interface of the module (functions used internally by the module).

   All functions in a module that can be `static` should be `static`.

   You might still have an omnibus header for your current project that includes all, or most, or the separate headers, but if you think of headers as defining the interfaces to modules, you will find that most consumer modules don't need to know about all possible provider modules.
2. The function `func()` is only used in `other.c` so the function should be made `static` so that it is only visible in `other.c`.  It should not go in a header unless some other file uses the function — and at that point, it is crucial that it does go into a header.

You may find useful information in these other questions, and there are, no doubt, a lot of other questions that would help too:

- [What are `extern` variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/)
- [Where to document functions in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568052/where-to-document-functions-in-c/)
- [Design principles — Best practices and design patterns for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492446/design-principles-best-practices-and-design-patterns-for-c-or-procedural-progr/)
- [Should I use `#include` in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers)

Answer (score 2):

If it's a BIG project, you almost certainly HAVE to have multiple headerfiles to make anything sensible out of your project.

I have worked on projects that have several thousand source files, and many hundred header files, totalling millions of lines. You couldn't put all those headerfiles together into one file, and do any meaningful work.

A headerfile should provide one "funcionality". So, if you have a program dealing with customer accounts, stock, invoices, and such, you may have one "customer.h", a "stock.h" and a "invoice.h". You'll probably also have a "dateutils.h" for calculating the "when does this invoice need to be paid by, and how long is it since the invoice was sent out, to send out reminders.

In general, keeping headerfiles SMALL is a good thing. If one headerfile needs something from another one, have it include that.

Of course, if a function is not used outside a particular file, it should not go in a headerfile, and to avoid "leaking names", it should be `static`. E.g:

```
 static void func(int x)
 {
    return x * 2;
 }
```

If, for some reason, you need to forward declare `func` (because some function before `func` needs to call `func`), then declare it at the beginning of the source file. There is no need to "spread it around" by adding it to a header file.

By marking it `static`, you are making it clear that "nobody else, outside this file, uses this function". If at a later stage, you find that "Hmm, this `func` is really useful in module B as well", then add it to a suitable header file (or make a new header file), and remove the `static`. Now, anyone reading the source file knows that they will need to check outside of this source file to make sure that any changes to `func` are OK in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, there is a header file per module describing its interface for clean separation of concerns/readability/re-usability.

If the function in other.c is local, there is no need to include it in the header file.